# Namespacing modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a little confused on module declarations and dependency injection.

I understand the [simpler](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5P8/18/) example, but I'm looking at a more "namespaced" approach for reusability.

I keep getting the error `Unknown provider: aServiceProvider <- aService` when using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5P8/22/) code, even though it renders.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['testFactories', 'testServices']);

angular.module('testFactories', []);

angular.module('testFactories')
.factory('aFactory', function(){
  return {
    sayHello: function(text){
      return "Factory says \"Hello " + text + "\"";
    },
    sayGoodbye: function(text){
      return "Factory says \"Goodbye " + text + "\"";
    }  
  }               
});

angular.module('testServices', []);

angular.module('testServices')
.service('aService', function(){
  this.sayHello = function(text){
    return "Service says \"Hello " + text + "\"";
  };        
  this.sayGoodbye = function(text){
    return "Service says \"Goodbye " + text + "\"";
  };   
});

function HelloCtrl($scope, aService, aFactory) {
  $scope.fromService = aService.sayHello("World");
  $scope.fromFactory = aFactory.sayHello("World");
}

function GoodbyeCtrl($scope, aService, aFactory) {
  $scope.fromService = aService.sayGoodbye("World");
  $scope.fromFactory = aFactory.sayGoodbye("World");
}

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document);
});
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `myApp` as a bootstrapping dependency :

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

Comment: Is this a correct answer or is there anyway you're stumbling upon ?